# Если у body появился класс modal open, то скрыть элемент и наоборот

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток,

Может кто сможет подсказать, задача следующая:

У `body` при открытии модального окна появляется класс modal-open, а при закрытии исчезает и мне нужно привязать к этому действие событие, которое будет скрывать/показывать кнопку открытия этого самого модального окна.

Делаю, я так, но почему-то не работает:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('modal-open')) {
  $('.imcallask-btn-mini').hide();
}

if ($('body').not('modal-open')) {
  $('.imcallask-btn-mini').show();
}
```

Comment: А вы где используете этот код?

Comment: Для этого не обязательно использовать jQuery. Достаточно CSS.

Comment: _Делаю, я так, но почему-то не работает:_ - на самом деле работает.

Comment: о каком модальном окне идет речь? самописном или используется какая-то библиотека?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант №1**. Вариант с одним использованием CSS:

```css
.modal {display:none;}

body.modal-open #open {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="data:text/javascript;charset=UTF-8,$(function() { $('#open').click(function() { $('.modal').show(); $('body').addClass('modal-open'); }); $('#close').click(function() { $('.modal').hide(); $('body').removeClass('modal-open'); }); });"></script>

<button id="open" class="imcallask-btn-mini">Открыть</button>
<button id="close">Закрыть</button>
  
<div class="modal">Модальное окно</div>
```

**Вариант №2**. Отлавливаем нажатие на кнопку открытия и закрытия модального окна:

```js
$(function() {
  /* Наш код отлавливания */
  $(document).on('click', '#open', function() {
    $('.imcallask-btn-mini').hide();
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#close', function() {
    $('.imcallask-btn-mini').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="data:text/javascript;charset=UTF-8,$(function() { $('#open').click(function() { $('.modal').show(); $('body').addClass('modal-open'); }); $('#close').click(function() { $('.modal').hide(); $('body').removeClass('modal-open'); }); });"></script>

<button id="open" class="imcallask-btn-mini">Открыть</button>
<button id="close">Закрыть</button>
  
<div class="modal">Модальное окно</div>
```

**Вариант №3**. Создаём интервал, который будет проверять наличия класса `.modal-open` у `body`:

```js
$(function() {
  /* Наш код интервала */
  setInterval(function() {
    if($('body').hasClass('modal-open')){
      $('.imcallask-btn-mini').hide();
    }else{
      $('.imcallask-btn-mini').show();
    };
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
.modal {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="data:text/javascript;charset=UTF-8,$(function() { $('#open').click(function() { $('.modal').show(); $('body').addClass('modal-open'); }); $('#close').click(function() { $('.modal').hide(); $('body').removeClass('modal-open'); }); });"></script>

<button id="open" class="imcallask-btn-mini">Открыть</button>
<button id="close">Закрыть</button>
  
<div class="modal">Модальное окно</div>
```

Comment: 3-ий вариант это то, что нужно было, так как окно можно закрыть на две кнопки и нажатием вне окна)) спасибо, большое)

Comment: @Waropank, третий вариант хуже всех из представленных. Если ж не нравится решение вообще без скриптов, то лучше в момент закрытия модального окна слать событие, что окно закрылось. Все библиотеки в которых реализованы модальные окна уже имеют такое событие. Для самописного модального окна тоже не составит труда добавить

Comment: @Grundy, на счёт третьего варианта - согласен)

Comment: @Grundy я в этом деле новичок, суть понял, но как это реализовать не имею представления, может подскажете?)

Comment: @Waropank, так все-таки, для модального окна используется какая-то библиотека?

Comment: @Grundy, это плагин для опенкарта, но я уже решил путем css, просто конкретный пример не подошел, пришлось немного переделать)

Comment: @Grundy, а вообще на будущее интересно, как это можно было сделать)